# CSS Image Slider not working after adding 6 photos

Tags: html, css, slide

I am using the Responsive CSS Image Slider from: 
https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi

It worked fine when I used 2, 4, or 5 pics.  However, when I tried using 6 photos the first and last photo stack together, the last slide is completely blank, and all the slides between have white space under them.

The following is the CSS code after I revised it:

```
@keyframes slidy{
0% { left: 0%; }
9.09% { left: 0%; }
18.18% { left: -100%; }
27.27% { left: -100%; }
36.36% { left: -200%; }
45.45% { left: -200%; }
54.54% { left: -300%; }
63.63% { left: -300%; }
72.72% { left: -400%; }
81.81% { left: -400%; }
90.90% { left: -500%; }
100% { left: -500%; }
}
.slide {
margin: 0 auto ;
max-width: 700px;
overflow: hidden;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
border-color: #f6a51c;
}
.slide figure {
position: relative;
width: 500%;
margin: 0 auto;
animation: 30s slidy infinite;
}
.slide figure img {
width: 20%;
float: left;
}
```

The following is the HTML code after I revised it:

```
<div class="slide">
<figure>
<img src="http://inmodemd.com/images/bodyfx-ba1.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://inmodemd.com/images/bodyfx-ba2.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://inmodemd.com/images/bodyfx-ba3.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://inmodemd.com/images/bodyfx-ba4.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://inmodemd.com/images/bodyfx-ba5.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://inmodemd.com/images/bodyfx-ba6.jpg" alt="" />
</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is 20%, the total width max is 700 and your trying to squeeze into that percentage. 5 is your max because each image is 20% of the 100% width. 20 x 5 is 100. 6 / 100 = 16.66666 , which means your images wont fit 100% across. Nice slider though. Hope this helps.

Comment: Every image would increase it by %100, it would be better to write a jquery or javascript that does this by numerating how many images then multiplying by that.

Comment: It works perfectly now!  Thanks for the explanation Cam!